# Thevenin's Theorem problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image: Pic1]

I don't understand why $(c)$ is same with a circuit when removing power source at $(b)$.

[image]

Isn't this same with this one? But how could this circuit could be $(c)$?

.
.

Comment: What you drew is the same as (c).  Take another look.

Comment: This question was already asked before on [EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223695/).

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the power supply in circuit $(b)$, then nodes $A$ and $D$ turn out to be the same node. Once you see this, you can go and analyze whether the resistors are connected in $(c)$ in the same way they were in $(b)$.

- $R_1$ is connected between $A=D$ and $B$ in both circuits.
- $R_2$ is connected between $A=D$ and $C$ in both circuits.
- $R_3$ is connected between $C$ and $D=A$ in both circuits.
- $R_4$ is connected between $B$ and $D=A$ in both circuits.

So $(b)$ and $(c)$ are equivalent.